# 500 Internal Server Error With Ajax Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iis, internal-server-error

*hi guys,*

Does anyone have any knowledge about the error seen at the image down below

[image: error]

The error occurs after waiting on the page for a while and then requesting an ajax call. The error is not repeated afterwards, but when the user waits again the error pops up again too. So the problem is about waiting on the page for a while, but could not find out why?

Thanks for the incoming responses

edit:link to image http://i53.tinypic.com/2ni8bcg.png

Comment: Did you get this solved this ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically an exception is occurring within your web service. It sounds like it's probably something timing out.

The first thing you should do is improve your logging (e.g. with [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)) so you can see exactly where the exception is being thrown... and then go about fixing it.

If it's a database connection timing out, it could be that you're forgetting to close the connection somewhere...

Comment: No exclusive description is given in elmah logs the same error is logged, so cant find the problem

Comment: @aeciftci: What do you mean by "no exclusive description"?